# What possible use does an iFrame have for security?

Tags: web-application, authentication, javascript, html

I'm looking at code for an old login form I'm redesigning. It's a simple table with two input fields for username and password.

But just before the end `</table>` tag there's a blank iFrame which looks like

```
<iframe style="height:0px;width:0px;visibility:hidden" src="about:blank">This is a security measure.</iframe>
```

What possible security measures could this provide? I can't think of any and can't ask the guy who put it there in the first place.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that the iframe is holding a cookie of some description.

Comment: Keep in mind that whoever put it there didn't necessarily know what they were doing. I've seen the most random things done in the name of "security", especially in legacy codebases.

Comment: @Sam How could it hold a cookie of _any_ description with a src of about:blank?

Comment: Michael is there any javascript in the form handler or validation routines that manipulates the content of the iframe? Is the iframe perhaps the target of the form and on receiving data it gives something back the posting page can process inline? Were they trying [to trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6532757/313192) (or not trigger) a browsers password remember features?

Comment: @Caleb - It's hard to judge by the example alone, but my bet would be this file the HTML code is from serves as a template for some CGI script to later fill it with other required parts that are missing on HTTP request. Having JS parts in separate files is a good practice in a multiple developer environment, where each developer only receives files they'd need to be concerned with. It's also easier to track versions and apply code and/or design changes. Either way, chances are the example OP posted is the only part of it he has access to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a security measure, as the description in the code implies. The `iframe` serves as a protection mechanism against [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) exploits through [browsers' own measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) against these very same attack types by preventing JavaScript access to frames and iframes when they're not published on the same domain. It isn't really necessary to write this part of HTML directly in the document, as it could as well be written by the same JavaScript that is latter manipulating its contents, but the developer of this solution probably wanted to make it clear to future developers that some external script is verifying the log-in form before it's posted and that the browsers XSS prevention mechanisms are used to achieve better end-user security while signing-in. This is also strongly implied by the lack of an ID for the iframe, which would make referencing it so much easier.

Developer would then attach a JavaScript `script` element to `iframe` DOM with a code that would look something like this:

```
window.onload = function () {

    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.width = "0px";
    iframe.height = "0px";
    iframe.style.visibility = "hidden";
    iframe.id = "noXSSframe";
    iframe.setAttribute("src", "about:blank");

    document.getElementById("formID").appendChild(iframe);

    iframe.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
        var myElement = document.createElement('script');
        myElement.setAttribute('src', '/content/test.js');
        myElement.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');

        iframe.contentDocument.body.appendChild(myElement);
    }, false);

}
```

<sup>This is just an example and is not necessarily the exact same method your developer chose, but should serve good enough for demonstration purposes.</sup>

This external JavaScript file that's just been attached to the iframe would then be written in such a way to account for being run through an iframe, referencing parent document object in a way that only a script located on the same domain is permitted, while any XSS injections replacing the called script with a script hosted outside of the parent document domain would clearly be denied access by browsers themselves. The only way to prevent browsers to enforce [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) for [XMLHttpRequests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) is by attaching additional headers to the server's HTTP response and explicitly allowing [cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing). This however isn't something XSS injections alone can tamper with.

In short, it's an elegant way to make sure the JavaScript that's responsible for manipulating, verifying and ultimately posting a log-in form (preparing and initiating a HTTP request) is indeed loaded from a file hosted on the same domain the log-in form is on, effectively preventing simple XSS injections. At the same time, it also prevents phishing sites from reusing this log-in form and sending log-in requests to another domain, if the iframe script does some additional verification, attaching unique response values that can be verified server-end to the form's [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) request.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you very much for the answer. Learned something new today.

Comment: Is it typical for web applications to make the .js in `extscript.setAttribute('src','somejavascriptfile.js');` dynamic and subject to XSS attacks?  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the threat.

Comment: What would be a good example of a unique response value to be included in the POST for verification?  Is a random nonce enough?

Comment: @makerofthings7 - No, I wouldn't say it's typical but the part of the HTML code OP included suggests it was done so in this case. XSS attack can't simply replace that URI value and expect a script from a different domain he'd be attaching to have access to the parent DOM. The only way to exploit this process with XSS is, if an attacker can count on some already existing script hosted on the same domain that he could reuse, and the chances for that are rather remote. But it can be done by adding `src` value to the `iframe` directly as well, but might have not been to better support versioning.

Comment: @makerofthings7 - A random nonce stored on the server on initial response, and then verified for same value and same request meta-data for both the external script and the end-user initiated POST request (i.e. session data). At least, that's how I'm doing it. I'm open to suggestions on how to improve this, if you see some potential problems with it, though. ;)

Comment: I tried implementing this and "createElement" and "createStandardElement" didn't seem to work.  [A slight modification to this did work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2682403/328397)  Also, why navigate like this: `.lastChild.firstChild.`

Comment: I made an edit to illustrate code that worked. It wasn't something I could paste into comments or put into an edit queue.  Please edit/delete/revise as needed.

Comment: @makerofthings7 - Cheers! Yes I've forgotten about that, I was writing out of my head with a bit of help from SO for what parts I _intentionally shook out of my head_ for sake of sanity. :) Frankly, I didn't even consider someone might want to reuse the code I wrote as the OP didn't imply he's after redoing it altogether, but merely asked what that `iframe` tag might suggest it's there for. But yeah, thanks again for making it a working demo!

Comment: (I deleted my last comment, it was no good). Once the token is exposed in the iframe, how is it used? I think if the variable is copied to the Parent in any form, it is vulnerable.  I'm envisioning a Prototype function "listening" for the secret, sending it off, and using it.

Comment: @makerofthings7 - Token should be attached to the form's post request as a new form field (not a preset one that can have a listener attached to it) when the user submits the sign-in form. This way, you're negating both event triggered and timer based listeners. As a precaution, also check for any event listeners on the submit form from within your iframe code and don't attach your token and post if any are detected. Alternatively, just [remove any listeners that shouldn't be there](http://www.josh-davis.org/node/4).

Comment: @makerofthings7 - RE _"why navigate like this: .lastChild.firstChild."_ I found an [interesting example (skip to lesson 3)](http://neil.fraser.name/news/2012/DOM_Tutorials/1.html). Now imagine your parent document was injected and what would that solve. I'm not trying to be patronizing, not in the least bit, but it's such a nice example that I had to put it somewhere. ;)

Comment: Is there a reference implementation (source code, or live) I feel like I might be re-inventing something that exists. `.lastChild.firstChild.` is null for a non injected form so I need to accomodate that.  This is getting bigger by the moment

Comment: @makerofthings7 - No you're not re-inventing the wheel. These solutions need their support on the server at the web application level, and since these would be different case by case, I don't believe there's any ready made solution _in the wild_ that you could use. Besides, even if there were examples, they would only include front-end code and only describe back-end part of it at best. You're asking all the right questions and progressing steadily towards a solution suitable for your use-case. I think that's all that matters and you should be nearly there anyway.

Comment: I think I need a working sample I can learn from and adapt.  I'm still missing "something".  Are there any sites out there I can compare implementations with?  (I feel bad I'm consuming this many comments, this is a record for me)