# How does DOCTYPE selection affect security of my AJAX app?

Tags: web-application, javascript, same-origin-policy, html-5, xml

I'm considering using [modern techniques to](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/33200/396) protect my Javascript code and am studying how the DOCTYPE element selection may impact that.  Specifically, the linked question used IFrames which are not permitted in certain selections of DOCTYPE.

In taking a broader view of this question, not specifically linked to the IFrame protection, are there any other considerations to take into account when choosing a DOCTYPE for my site?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333398/does-html-doctype-make-the-page-more-secure

Comment: Since DOCTYPE is a layout engine selector, I don't see this as a potential security but merely a compatibility concern. That said, it would be a good practice to only use AJAX relevant parts of your code on user agents that are compliant with a selected DOCTYPE and serve others a non-AJAX version.

Answer (score 1):

`Document types` (or `DOCTYPE`) is a declarative and semantical element which is part of the `W3C` specification regarding markup languages documents (such as `XHTML`).

Their presence (or non-presence) within a markup document does not influence a whatever security aspect when they are being rendered and processed by a web browser.

If you are writing an `XHTML 1.1` document, [there is](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) a DOCTYPE for it, same if you are writing an `HTML5` document.

We say that these elements are essentially *semantical* rather than *functional*.