# Is the src of an iframe safe for user input?

Tags: xss, javascript, html, iframe

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"
  src="javascript:alert(1)">
```

I would like to know if the `src` attribute of an `iframe` is safe for user input ?
I found [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33200/what-possible-use-does-an-iframe-have-for-security), but my doubt is that I tried the code provided in  the answer and it doesn't do anything with the `sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"` attribute.

I'm allowing user to post videos, doing so when the user post a link on the backend a get request is made to get the correct value in `meta` tag.
However nothing is stopping OP to post a link to www.my-site-with-fake-meta-tag.com and try to do something funny.

So I could white list some domains, but it's an annoying process. Beside every site I checked uses an iframe src for user submitted content.

Comment: Ban `javascript:` and `data:` urls and rely on same-origin more than sandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, a user-supplied `<iframe src=...>` is not safe.**

The `alert()` in your example doesn't fire because the `sandbox` property automatically blocks modal dialogs (alert boxes). But since you have set `allow-scripts`, the JS code is still executed in the background. And because `allow-same-origin` is set, it is even executed on the same domain as the embedding page. Using these settings together makes the sandbox attribute useless because you're giving the sandbox full privileges.

As a proof of concept, just use another function, e.g. `document.write()`:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" src="javascript:document.write(document.domain)">
```

Or add the `allow-modals` directive (which interestingly isn't currently documented):

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-modals" src="javascript:alert(1)">
```

Be aware that instead of the `javascript:` scheme an attacker could also inject a `data:` URI:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-modals" src="data:text/html,<script>alert(1)</script>">
```

If your plan was to give the embedded page as few permissions as possible, you could have just left the sandbox attribute empty:

```
<iframe sandbox src="...">
```

Comment: Would it be fine with a user supplied `src` for an `iframe` without any `sandbox` attribute at all?

Comment: @Anders Youtube requires allow-scripts and allow-same-origin for some reasons.. Anyway Virtually every site that has sharable content uses an iframe. Do they simply parse for XSS ? User submit link X, Server check meta tag to display thumbnail on user post, thumbnail displayed in iframe.

Comment: @Ced: you only need that relaxation for youtube if you want to interact with the video from the top page's JS

Comment: @dandavis I'm not sure what you mean by `interact with the video from the top page JS`. https://jsfiddle.net/mzd7n53a/ if you remove either one of `allow-scripts allow-same-origin`, the video will simply not load. Even though the interaction is not with js.

Comment: @Ced That's because Youtube requires Javascript to run. If you trust YT, you can just leave out the sandbox attribute entirely.

Comment: @ced: hhmm, that's new, but you can remove all the sandbox stuff and use the battle-tested SOP